# How to animate UIView while hiding or unhiding

Tags: ios, iphone, animation, button, uiview

I want to animate the UIView while hiding or unhiding it.

I have a button which loads the UIView as "view.hidden=FALSE"and I hide it by "view.hidden=TRUE".

Is there a way of hiding/unhiding while animating it?

Comment: What do you mean by animating it? Do you mean you want it to fade out or do you mean it will be moving around etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this :
by default put alpha of your view is 0.0.

```
yourViewObject.alpha = 0.0f;
```

when you are trying to unhide your view use this:

```
yourViewObject.hidden = NO;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f
                     animations:^{
                         yourViewObject.alpha = 1.0;

                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         //Done
                     }];
```

And at hiding use this

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f
                         animations:^{
                             yourViewObject.alpha = 0.0;

                         } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                             //Done
                               yourViewObject.hidden = YES;
                         }];
```

Comment: appropriate answer..!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean 100% but you can fade out the view like this...

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                 animations:^(){
                     self.view.alpha = 0.0;
                 }
                 completion:nil];
```